# Entire Lookup Row to Appear in Dropdown

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list, lookup-column

I hope I can explain this clearly.  I am working in SharePoint 2013 and created a custom list that I pulling the data from that list into another list using lookup columns. For example, ID# is one of the lookup columns. That works great!

Objective:  is to have the lookup columns to appear as a dropdown in the other list along with the other columns connected to the line item.  I was able to get the ID#, but the other two columns connected to the ID do not appear in the drop down, but do appear in the custom list after the form is saved.

Question:  Is there a way show the entire row in the dropdown?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a calculated column to List1 that concatenates `ID`, `Title`, and `Customer Name`.

Then you can Lookup to the calculated column in List2.